# Plotting bar graph and line plot on the same graph in Time series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to add a two side by side bar graph and a line graph for three columns of result dataset "Residential_Permit_Value","NonResidential_Permit_Value","Unemployment_Rate"  considering the "Date" column as index and the bar graphs are showing but the line graph which is unemployment is not showing. The reason I created the result dataset is because I wanted to group by the data based on only years and analyze the dataset annually.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib as mlp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import datetime
from datetime import date
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 100)
df = pd.read_csv('Monthly_Economic_Indicators.csv')
df.head()


def dateobject(date):
        dateobject = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(date), "%Y-%m-%d")
        dateobject = dateobject.isoformat()
        return dateobject
df['Date'] = df['Date'].map(dateobject)
df.head(4)


re_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(re_df['Date'])

# Group 'Residential_Permit_Value' and 'NonResidential_Permit_Value' by year

result = re_df.groupby(re_df['Date'].dt.year).agg({'Residential_Permit_Value': 'sum', 'NonResidential_Permit_Value':'sum', 'Unemployment_Rate': 'mean'}).reset_index()

result = result.set_index(['Date'])
result

# create the bar grapghs and line plot

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (25, 22))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax3 = ax1.twinx()

result['Residential_Permit_Value'].plot(kind='bar', color='pink', ax=ax1, position=0, width=0.25, label="Residential_Permit_Value")
ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc='lower left')
result['NonResidential_Permit_Value'].plot(kind='bar', color='yellow', ax=ax2, position=1, width=0.25, label="Non-Residential_Permit_Value")
ax2.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.05, 1., 1), loc='lower left')
result['Unemployment_Rate'].plot(kind='line', color='red',ax=ax3, label='Unemployment Rate')
ax3.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.05, 1., .102), loc='lower right')

ax1.set_ylabel = ('Residential_Permit_Value')
ax2.set_ylabel = ('NonResidential_Permit_Value')



def add_labels(ax):
    for rect in ax.patches:
        y_value = rect.get_height()
        x_value = rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2.

        label ='${:,.2f}'.format(y_value)

        ax.annotate(            
            label,                      
            (x_value, y_value),        
            xytext=(0, -100),         
            textcoords="offset points", 
            ha='center',                
            va='center',rotation='vertical',weight='bold')  

add_labels(ax1)
add_labels(ax2)
add_labels(ax3)


xtl=[]
xtl=[item.get_text()[:10] for item in ax1.get_xticklabels()]
xtl= (pd.to_datetime(xtl).strftime("%Y"))
_=ax1.set_xticklabels(xtl)


plt.show()
```

Comment: This is the link of the original dataset [link](https://data.calgary.ca/Business-and-Economic-Activity/Monthly-Economic-Indicators/7cvb-8ame) _italic_ **bold**   thank you

Comment: What is `re_df`? You are using it without defining it...

Comment: @RozitaGhasemi in the link that you provided in the file there are no columns: Residential_Permit_Value, NonResidential_Permit_Value, Unemployment_Rate.